# Error in sum record in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `votes` with the following records:

```
 id id_product vots
  1     1        5
  2     1        5
  3     1       3.5
  4     1       3.5
```

He conducted the query taking two data in each one, ie took into account the votes `4.5` and `5`, and the other query in the same query `3.5` and `4`

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN votes IN (4.5, 5) THEN votes ELSE 0 END) AS in_5_vote,
    SUM(CASE WHEN votes IN (3.5, 4) THEN votes ELSE 0 END) AS in_4_vote
FROM votesproducts
WHERE id_product=?
```

**The error:**

When printing results `$in_5_vote` I get:

> 0.5000

When printing results from `$in_4_vote` I get the same result:

> 0.5000

**What I wish:**

This bad if you can observe in the table record should show these results:

From `$in_5_vote` the following result (5 + 5):

> 10

From `$in_4_vote` the following result (3.5 + 3.5):

> 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `/COUNT(*)` is unnecessary if you simply want to add the votes of similar category. Try this instead:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN votes IN (4.5, 5) THEN votes ELSE 0 END) AS in_5_vote,
    SUM(CASE WHEN votes IN (3.5, 4) THEN votes ELSE 0 END) AS in_4_vote
FROM votesproducts
WHERE id_product=?
```